# Find length of longest string in Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a faster way to find the length of the longest string in a Pandas DataFrame than what's shown in the example below?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = ['ab', 'bcd', 'dfe', 'efghik']
x = np.repeat(x, 1e7)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1'])

print df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
# result --> 6
```

It takes about 10 seconds to run `df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()` when timing it with IPython's `%timeit`.

Comment: You might be able to save some time by simply using `map(len)`-- the `lambda` does nothing but waste time here.  Maybe 25% or so, I'd guess.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

DSM's suggestion seems to be about the best you're going to get without doing some manual microoptimization:

```
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.str.len().max()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(len).max()
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
```

Note that explicitly using the `str.len()` method doesn't seem to be much of an improvement. If you're not familiar with IPython, which is where that very convenient `%timeit` syntax comes from, I'd definitely suggest giving it a shot for quick testing of things like this.

**Update** Added screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I came to the same conclusion when DSM commented on `map(len)`. Shaves off about 40% compared to `len(lambda x: len(x))` method.

Comment: One point to make is that the str.len method is NaN etc. robust.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes you want the length of the longest string **in bytes**. This is relevant for strings that use fancy Unicode characters, in which case the length in bytes is greater than the regular length. This can be very relevant in specific situations, e.g. for **database writes**.

```
col_bytes_len = int(df[col_name].astype(bytes).str.len().max())
```

Remarks:

- Using `astype(bytes)` is more reliable than using `str.encode(encoding='utf-8')`. This  is because `astype(bytes)` also works correctly with a column that has mixed dtypes.
- The output is enclosed in `int()` because the output is otherwise a numpy object.
- Iff having an encoding error, then instead of `df[col_name].astype(bytes)`, consider:

  - `df[col_name].str.encode('utf-8')`
  - `df[col_name].str.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace')` (last choice)

Comment: got this error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 126: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Despite of two encoding solutions, I still get an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0263' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)` for both.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a minor addition, you might want to loop through all object columns in a data frame:

```
for c in df:
    if df[c].dtype == 'object':
        print('Max length of column %s: %s\n' %  (c, df[c].map(len).max()))
```

This will prevent errors being thrown by bool, int types etc.

Could be expanded for other non-numeric types such as 'string_', 'unicode_' i.e.

```
if df[c].dtype in ('object', 'string_', 'unicode_'):
```

Comment: Unless there is an empty value represented by `NaN` in the dataframe then you will receive the following error: `object of type 'float' has no len()`. A-B-Bs answer above converts to `str` to accommodate for this.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answers, in particular Marius and Ricky which were very helpful.

Given that most of us are optimising for coding time, here is a quick extension to those answers to return all the columns' max item length as a series, sorted by the maximum item length per column:

```
mx_dct = {c: df[c].map(lambda x: len(str(x))).max() for c in df.columns}
pd.Series(mx_dct).sort_values(ascending =False)
```

Or as a one liner:

```
pd.Series({c: df[c].map(lambda x: len(str(x))).max() for c in df).sort_values(ascending =False)
```

Adapting the original sample, this can be demoed as:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [['ab', 'bcd'], ['dfe', 'efghik']]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1','col2'])

print(pd.Series({c: df[c].map(lambda x: len(str(x))).max() for c in df}).sort_values(ascending =False))
```

Output:

```
col2    6
col1    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = ['ab', 'bcd', 'dfe', 'efghik']
x = np.repeat(x, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1'])

# get longest string index from column
indx = df["col1"].str.len().idxmax()

# get longest string value
df["col1"][indx] # <---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster (depending on the size of your dataframe):

```
    maxsize=[df[x].astype('string').array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
```

or

```
    maxsize=[df[x].array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
```

for small data frames, it is not necessary:

```
x = ['ab', 'bcd', 'dfe', 'efghik']
x = np.repeat(x, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1'])
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.str.len().max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(len).max()
%timeit -n 100 [df[x].astype('string').array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
171 µs ± 5.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
126 µs ± 4.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
124 µs ± 3.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
143 µs ± 4.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But the bigger the data frame is, the faster it gets:

```
x = ['ab', 'bcd', 'dfe', 'efghik']
x = np.repeat(x, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1'])
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.str.len().max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(len).max()
%timeit -n 100 [df[x].astype('string').array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
1.08 ms ± 57.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.2 ms ± 9.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
878 µs ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
705 µs ± 3.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) 


x = ['ab', 'bcd', 'dfe', 'efghik']
x = np.repeat(x, 10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1'])
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.str.len().max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()
%timeit -n 100 df.col1.map(len).max()
%timeit -n 100 [df[x].astype('string').array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
8.87 ms ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
11 ms ± 25.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
7.88 ms ± 36.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.81 ms ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Since I was testing different methods on my data frame, I had to convert the dtype first (df[x].astype('string'))

If it is already a Series of dtype string, it is 10% faster:

```
%timeit -n 100 [df[x].array.astype('U').dtype.itemsize // 4 for x in df.columns]
5.26 ms ± 95.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This here is even faster:

```
%timeit -n 100 [df[x].astype('string').array.astype('S').dtype.itemsize for x in df.columns]
3.89 ms ± 207 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 [df[x].array.astype('S').dtype.itemsize for x in df.columns]
3.26 ms ± 31.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But you might get encoding errors:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you let NumPy decide what data type to use, you automatically know the biggest item:

```
df.col1.astype('string').array.astype('S')
Out[173]: 
array([b'ab', b'ab', b'ab', ..., b'efghik', b'efghik', b'efghik'],
      dtype='|S6')
```