# Length of max string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My question is similar to the following post/question:
[Find the length of the longest string in a Pandas DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295334/find-the-length-of-the-longest-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

However, I'm wondering how to find the longest string across a dataframe with multiple columns.  The solution for the above-mentioned post is fixed for a single column.  How would I evaluate all columns in a data frame and find the longest length?  Note, the longest item may not be a string. It may be a long decimal.

Comment: won't `df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max().max()` work?

Comment: i dont know, will it? :)

Comment: I expect it, I just tried on a df of mixes types and it worked

Comment: @EdChum that will count the `.` in decimals as a character too. For example `2.5` will have `len` as 3. But that maybe something OP wants.

Comment: @ComputerFellow the OP hasn't well defined this problem they should post a representative sample data and desired output

Comment: @EdChum, completely agreed, and a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by searching for maximum within columns and then finding maximum over the result:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'c1': ['abc','a','ghjhkkhgjgj'],
        'c2': np.random.randint(1,1e9,3)
    })
df
      c1    c2
0   abc 843828735
1   a   914636142
2   ghjhkkhgjgj 155217279

max(df.astype('str').applymap(lambda x: len(x)).max())
11
```

In case you want the string itself:

```
mask = df.astype('str').applymap(lambda x: len(x)) >= max(df.astype('str').applymap(lambda x: len(x)).max())
df[mask]

     c1 c2
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   ghjhkkhgjgj NaN
```

**Timing comparison vs EdChum's suggestion**

```
%timeit max(df.astype('str').applymap(lambda x: len(x)).max())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop

%timeit df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max().max()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop
```

(please take into account, this is still a small df)

Comment: I expect `df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max().max()` to be faster for large dfs as this iterates over the columns whilst `applymap` iterates over each element

Comment: The other thing to consider here is htat `str.len` is `NaN` tolerant

Comment: @EdChum as soon as you do `df.astype(str)` there are no `NaNs` in df

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov yes that's true, if the dtype was mixes then without the cast then it would handle non str types and `NaN` and return `NaN`