# Create a column which is string who has the max length within each rows - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
d = { 'col1' : ['John', 'Mark Dupont', np.nan],
      'col2' : ['John Doe', 'Mark 40', 'Edith'],
      'col3' : ['John Doe 40', np.nan, 'Edith']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

and I want the following result:

```
d = { 'col1' : ['John', 'Mark Dupont', np.nan],
      'col2' : ['John Doe', 'Mark 40', 'Edith'],
      'col3' : ['John Doe 40', np.nan, 'Edith'],
      'Name' : ['John Doe 40', 'Mark Dupont', 'Edith']}
```

In each rows, there is different version of name identity for the same person, some random missing values and some columns have the same value in a row.

I want to create a column which is composed by the max length for each rows. I imagine I have to use : `len().max()` and somehow put it in a `df.loc[ ]` but I couldn't find the right way.

I found the related post but for one entire column : [Find length of longest string in Pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295334/find-length-of-longest-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column)

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You're *almost* there/ "i couldn't find the right way" isn't quite a proper SO question.  Show your best attempt [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), rather than expecting us to do all of the coding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
You can simply replace NaNs with an empty string '' and find a max:

```
df = df.fillna('')
df['Name'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Option 2:
Use apply and explicitly skip NaNs while finding a maximum:

```
df['Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: max([l for l in x.values if not pd.isnull(l)], key=len), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That works  The solution seams so simple when it's written.. I just learn python since one month and I began a project of mapping the best distilleries in Martinique according to data collecting from web scrapping. The data are so messy and gives me headhaches !

Comment: @R1mk4 I am happy it helps :) Working with the data is always a challenge but also a great fun. Good luck with your studying and have fun ;) Please mark the answer as a solution, if you like it.