# Series [] and .loc[] sometimes returns a single value, and sometimes unexpectedly a single element Series containing the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

In the code below, I am trying to find the longest string in a DataFrame column.

Depending on the length of the column, the function below (maxstr), returns a single value for short columns (as expected), and a single element series for long columns (I didn't expect this).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

I used methods discussed in [Find length of longest string in Pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21295334/12822130)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

As the data is large, I resort to displaying the information on the dataframe and series as I go along.

### Read dataframe from clipboard

```py
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], na_values='')
```

```py
print(f'{type(df)=}')
print(f'{df.shape=}')
print(f'{df.dtypes=}')
print(f'{df.columns=}')
```

```
type(df)=<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
df.shape=(581, 6)
df.dtypes=CID           int64
TITLE        object
FIRSTNAME    object
FUNCTION     object
PHONE        object
EMAIL        object
dtype: object
df.columns=Index(['CID', 'TITLE', 'FIRSTNAME', 'FUNCTION', 'PHONE', 'EMAIL'], dtype='object')
```

### Function to return the maximum length string equivalent in a column/series

```py
def maxstr(ser: pd.Series):
    print(f'{type(ser)=}')

    print(f'\n{type(ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax())=}')
    print(f'{type(ser[ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()])=}')

    # should return a single value and not a series
    return ser[ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()]
```

### working with a short column (n=50), I get an int (as expected)

```py
short = df.head(50)
short_return = maxstr(short['CID'])
```

```
type(ser)=<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

type(ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax())=<class 'tuple'>
type(ser[ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()])=<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

### woking with long columns from the same dataframe (same data) (n=100), I get a series (not expected ??)

```py
long = df.head(100)
long_return = maxstr(long['CID'])
```

```
type(ser)=<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
    
type(ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax())=<class 'tuple'>
type(ser[ser.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()])=<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

### In both cases, we find the same int value (but one in a series, and the other as a single value)

```py
short_return == long_return.iloc[0]
```

```
True
```

### The int value is unique, so it occurs once in the dataframe column

```py
value = short_return
print(f'The value: {value=}')
print(f'{sum(short["CID"] == value)=}')
print(f'{sum(long["CID"] == value)=}')
```

```
The value: value=1937
sum(short["CID"] == value)=1
sum(long["CID"] == value)=1
```

Comment: This question is 5 screenfuls long, please reduce it to the absolute minimum lines of code needed [mcve]. Ideally that should be 5 lines long, if you have 5 examples. (We don't need any of the prints, docstrings or comments.)

Comment: Thanks I will try to shorten it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion problem is duplicated index values, so if `idxmax` return `tuple`, which is duplicated, is returned not scalar, but all duplicated rows in selection.

Simple solution for avoid it is create default index, here change:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], na_values='')
```

to:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', na_values='')
```

for no `MultiIndex`, but default `RangeIndex`.

Check it if `RangeIndex`:

```
print (df.index)
```

---

Solution if need `MultiIndex` is remove duplicated values:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], na_values='')
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```